# Laravel Table relationship Dynamodb

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have an question
I want to display all posts in a page

Here is my dynamodb

> users Table: user_id | email | name | password
>
> posts Table: id | body | user_id

user_id for me to link, so one user has many posts.

I just simply use Auth::user()->user_id to get user id and request body to create a new post item

but how to foreach the following?

> name(from users) : body(from posts)

Post.php

```
class Post extends \BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbModel
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = array('id');
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends \BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbModel implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;    
    public function posts()
    {    
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }    
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = array('email');
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
}
```

PostController.php

```
 class PostController extends Controller
    {
        public function getDashboard()
        {
            $posts = Post::all();        
            return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
        }
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
@foreach($posts as $post)               
                <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
                    by {{ $post->users->name}}                  

        @endforeach
```

Error when load dashboard page

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

but it works with just $post->body
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually in laravel table should have **id** as primary key.

The relationship mentioned is not correct

**Post Model :**

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','user_id');
    }
```

**User Model**

```
public function posts()
{    
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id','user_id');
}
```

Comment: still have the same error. This correct?" {{ $post->users->first_name }}  ".  For the id as primary key, should I change the users table attribute from user_id to id?

Comment: It should be like this {{ $post->user->first_name }}. it is user and not users

Comment: it have another error after changing to "user"  ---   `ErrorException in BelongsTo.php line 50:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, instance of BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbQueryBuilder given, called in MyProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 806 and defined (View: MyProject\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)`

Comment: instead of extending \BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbModel extend Model and check it. use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Comment: can you check whether your user_id in posts table is foreign key referenced with user table. If not make it a foreign key reference and also check whether it is nullable field

Comment: I found that AWS Dynamodb is not support foreign key. And there is no nullable field. How can I do?

Comment: DynamoDB does not support relations as sql databases do. So it is kind of useless to define `hasMany` and `belongsTo` methods in models. Instead in code you fetch the user and its posts using 2 different queries as per [this github issue on baopham/laravel-dynamodb](https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb/issues/47)